# UIView inside UIScrollView issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

If I have a UIView as a subview of the UIScrollView and this scroll view is a horizontal scroll view, how do I know when the UIView (the subview) is out of the UIScrollView so that I can remove it as a subview and store it somewhere else for reuse? Is there a delegate for this?

Comment: What is the overall use case? Usually you would leave the UIView in there for when they scroll back.

Comment: the use case is i want to have a pool of UIView, as there is only 3 subview at a time seen on the screen.. when they scroll back I want to reuse the UIView from my pool. Kind of like the UITableView cell where you can reuse

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a delegate for this, you need to use the UIScrollViewDelegate.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

The method scrollViewDidScroll tell you when a scroll append, so in this function you could test the contentOffset property (*scrollview.contentOffset.x*) and then compare it with your view position and size (*myView.frame.origin.x + myView.frame.size.width*).

So basicaly you should do

```
if(scrollview.contentOffset.x > (myView.frame.origin.x + myView.frame.size.width))
 //Remove my view to reuse it
```

If you only have 2 views to display and just want to re-use each view you could find the view currently displayed like this:

```
    //Assuming your views had the same width and it is store in the pageWidth variable
    float currPosition = photoGalleryScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    //We look for the selected page by comparing his width with the current scroll view position
    int selectedPage = roundf(currPosition / pageWidth);
    float truePosition = selectedPage * pageWidth;
    int zone = selectedPage % 2;
    BOOL view1Active = zone == 0;
    UIView *nextView = view1Active ? view2 : view1;
    UIView *currentView = view1Active ? view1 : view2;

    //We search after the next page
    int nextpage = truePosition > currPos + 1 ? selectedPage-1 : selectedPage+1;

    //then we compare our next page with the selectd page
    if(nextpage > selectedPage){
         //show next view
    }
    else{
         //show previous view
    }
```

After that you need to add some content to nextView, add it to the scroll view and remove currentView when its hidden.

Comment: what if I want to know whether this view was gone because the user swipe it horizontally left or horizontally right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` and some custom code to achieve this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set theScrollView's delegate
    theScrollView.delegate = self;
}

//custom method for determining visible rect of scrollView
- (CGRect)visibleRectForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; {
    CGFloat scale = (CGFloat) 1.0 / scrollView.zoomScale;
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin = scrollView.contentOffset;
    visibleRect.size = scrollView.bounds.size;
    float theScale = 1.0 / scale;
    visibleRect.origin.x *= theScale;
    visibleRect.origin.y *= theScale;
    visibleRect.size.width *= theScale;
    visibleRect.size.height *= theScale;
    return visibleRect;
}

//UIScrollView Delegate method
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    BOOL viewVisisble = CGRectContainsRect([self visisbleRectForScrollView:theScrollView], theView.frame);
    if(!viewVisisble) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: visibleRect is a CGRect and yet you are returning a CGFloat?

Comment: Obviously that was a mistake, you can see it said CGRect in the code within the method